# HTML embeded swf behaving awkwardly

Tags: html, actionscript-3, embed, flash

I have recently completed a Flash Website and tested it out offline on a localhost, and it worked perfectly. I uploaded the website: http://ygorpg.eb2a.com , And that's when things started to get weird.

When offline, I put the website's music to loop. It worked great, the song would reach to the end, then replay.

But online, it reaches half-way through the song, "assumes" that it finished, and loops. That isn't all though, there are countless other problems, and they all point to the fact that the Flash website/song aren't being fully loaded.

**I'll keep this short and simple:** I want the swf and song to start playing *after* they've
finished loading and not *while* they're loading. How do I do this?

This is how I'm loading the swf at the moment:

```
<html>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#000000">
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="RPG33.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you load them then?

Comment: I'm loading the swf by embeding it, as shown in the code, and the song is called by the swf by using the standard URLRequest method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a preloader.
There are a lot of good examples for flash already available online so I won't try to detail it here, but the general idea is that the app should start in another 'state'/screen where it waits for all the required resources to load, after which it should move on to the rest of your app.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, but I didn't know the naming for it. Thanks alot!